# Creating a loop script in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have been asked to create a loop script in SQL which will pull table name, column name and an operation from a list which I will create. Then loop through each row in the list and create a query. See below my thinking.

- Table 1, Column x, Sum;
- Table 2, Column z, Sum;
- Table 3, Column F, Sum;

```
Loop
  Select  operation(ColumnName)    
  From TableName 
End Loop (When there is nothing left in the list)
```

Am I going along the correct path with this or am I going wrong somewhere? Or is it even possible?

Any help you can offer will be really appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to create a loop at all? Loops are something you want to do in a programming language; SQL isn't a programming language. You'll almost *always* be better off with a set-based operation.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? Also is `{ Table1, ColumnX, Sum; Table2, Column z, Sum; Table3, ColumnF, Sum;}` a valid format for your input list?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop, you can use a simple select statement to generate the queries, for example:

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9321d1f91de5af18aa3952a84d8b4888)**

```
create table query_parts(table_name varchar(100), col_name varchar(100), agg_func varchar(100));

insert into query_parts
select 'Table1', 'Column X', 'Sum';

insert into query_parts
select 'Table2', 'Column Y', 'Avg';
```

```
select 'select ' + agg_func + '(' + quotename(col_name) + ') from ' + quotename(table_name) + ';' as query
from query_parts
```

**UPDATE**

If you also want to execute the queries, you can use the following example to get started:

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=eee8fc827cffdf727b56261aeb02eb55)**

```
create table query_parts(id int identity, table_name varchar(100), col_name varchar(100), agg_func varchar(100), result decimal(12,6));

insert into query_parts (table_name, col_name, agg_func)
select 'Table1', 'Column_X', 'Sum';

insert into query_parts (table_name, col_name, agg_func)
select 'Table1', 'Column_Y', 'Avg';

create table Table1 (Column_X int, Column_Y decimal(12,6))

insert into Table1
select 5, 5;

insert into Table1
select 10, 10;
```

Loop through the `query_parts` table and execute queries:

```
declare @i int;
declare @query nvarchar(1000);

select @i = min(id) 
from query_parts;

while (@i is not null)
begin
  select @query = ('update query_parts set result = (' 
                   +  ('select ' + agg_func + '(' + quotename(col_name) + ') from ' + quotename(table_name))
                   + ') where id = ' + cast(@i as nvarchar))
  from query_parts
  where id = @i;

  exec sp_executesql @query;

  select @i = min(id) 
  from query_parts
  where id > @i;
end
```

Comment: *"`[' + col_name + ']`"* isn't injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Thanks Rohitvats, this gives me a good starting point! Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Larnu, oh yeah, forgot about `quotename`, hadn't used it in a while, fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your help.

Your above solution returns a list of queries. But what I am actually looking is for the queries to run and return results, instead of returning a full list of queries. Hope I am clear. 

Thanks

Comment: @Sean, answer updated, hope this helps, please upvote and accept if it does.

Comment: @rohitvats Hi, thanks for your help. I am attempting to do this in teradata and unfortunately some of the syntax you have used isnt working. any modifications you could make to help would be appreciated!  

I have read I am unable to declare variables in Teradata, is this true? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ToSquare INT
DECLARE @Square INT
SET @ToSquare = 0
WHILE @ToSquare < 100
BEGIN
    SET @ToSquare = @ToSquare + 1
    SET @Square = @ToSquare * @ToSquare
    IF @Square > 1000
        BREAK
    PRINT @Square
END
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to this. Also, why use a `WHILE` when this would certainly be faster with a Tally?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can using CURSOR.
Some thing like this:

```
DECLARE @your_Cursor CURSOR 
    SET @your_Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
        FOR SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName 
    OPEN @your_Cursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @your_Cursor 
    INTO @value
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        -- do something 
        END

    CLOSE @your_Cursor 
    DEALLOCATE @your_Cursor
```